# Trying to update field in a feature Without "attInspector" ...Using ArcGis JavScript api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I cannot find any changes in the field. Please help me out.

I am attaching my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++)
{
  feature = features[i];
  feature.attributes["X"] = Value;

  updateFeature.getLayer().applyEdits(null, [feature], null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing whether the array of features match `updateFeature` variable, and whether you meant for `Value` to be uppercase, I feel like I'm shooting in the dark with this answer. You may need to `refresh()` the layer once teh changes have been complete. Remember that `applyEdits()` is an asynchronous task, and the information may not have made it to the server and back to the browser by the time you check it.

Here's an example taken from your code below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++)
{
  feature = features[i];
  feature.attributes["X"] = Value;
}
// update all the features at once.
updateFeature.getLayer().applyEdits(null, features, null).then(
  function (response) {
    updateFeature.getLayer().refresh();
    // query again for the feature after update-end.
    // this updateFeature may be disconnected from the layer
    // and not updated.
  }
);
```